# Model specification for MNL model with multiple interactions between categorial variables

Tags: r, statistics, regression, logistic-regression, categorical-data

**Background**: (non-essential for question but should add context). I am conducting a discrete choice experiment. To determine my experimental design (which levels of attribute levels are presented to whom to be most efficient) I need to specify a Multinomial Logistic Regression (MNL) model. The output from this model (betas and standard errors) are used as inputs for the experimental design software so my model needs to be roughly the best it can be for this stage. After this, I can change the model based on results.

**My question**: This is broad question relating to model spec and not just choice modelling. In my model, I have multiple categorical attributes that need to be interacted with each other, similarly to how sociodemographic would be included in a model (the reason is related to choice modelling and the options available to respondents restricts the data so must be interactions). What would be a good way of estimating a suitable model for the purposes of generating my experimental design (because at this stage, I cannot simply try different options, and adapt my model).

**Example:**
If I have the following categorical variable with 4 levels:

```
QUALITY of LIFE [QoL]: [1] Very bad, [2] bad, [3] good, [4] very good.
DRUG TYPE [DRUG]: [1] Four a day, [2] Three a day, [3] Two a day, [4] Once a day
```

When specifying my model, I have a few categorical variables that need to be interacted like this, but can't include them all. Would a good option be to include lowest and highest levels for each categorical variables, using the lowest level as a reference category?. E.g.,

```
Utility = asc + 1*(QoL1*DRUG1) + 2(QoL4*DRUG1)
```

I have been told that for categorical variables, people rarely use more than two levels for interpretation as it becomes quite messy? Would using the lowest (as a reference) and highest levels be a suitable option without being able to test it in the data?

I current have ~50 options for interactions and need to reduce this to not over-specify my model, but I need to do this without being able to use and run data to look at its effect. Any advice on how people tend to start to specify models with multiple categorical variables (and interactions between them) would be extremely useful.

Thanks in advance!